# Can someone explain how angularjs $utils evalProperty works

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have been using the ng grid and had to get inside their code to resolve an issue. Following is a snippet of code from ng grid debug JavaScript file

```
 var value = item[condition.column] || (col.field ? item[col.field.split('.')[0]] :  $utils.evalProperty(item, col.field));
```

Can someone please tell me what is this `evalProperty`?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to be working on a library using ng-grid 2.x and came across an issue with this same method.

Using the javascript debugger, I put a breakpoint on a method call to $utils.evalProperty, stepped into the function, and discovered it's actually part of ng-grid:

```
angular.module('ngGrid.services').factory('$utilityService', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
// ...
  this.evalProperty = function (entity, path) {
    return $parse(preEval('entity.' + path))({ entity: 
  };
```